# django-rating filtering in django

Tags: django

I am trying to do something pretty simple and trivial but with no luck.

I am using django-rating to rate specific objects on my site.
On my model which I wanted to rate I have a field :

```
rating = RatingField(range=5)
```

Now , all I want is to filter all of the objects which have a rate of 2 and aobve for example.

If rating was IntegerField for example, I would only need to do :

```
objects.filter( rating__gte = 2)
```

how can I do the same using django-rating ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading [django-rate documentation](https://github.com/dcramer/django-ratings) I found this trick to sort by rate:

```
# In this example, ``rating`` is the attribute name for your ``RatingField``
qs = qs.extra(select={
    'rating': '((100/%s*rating_score/(rating_votes+%s))+100)/2' 
               % (MyModel.rating.range, MyModel.rating.weight)
                      })
qs = qs.order_by('-rating')
```

Perhaps you can modify this code sample and use [extra where](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) to get your results:

```
qs = qs.extra(where=[
         '((100/%s*rating_score/(rating_votes+%s))+100)/2 >= 2 ' % 
          (MyModel.rating.range, MyModel.rating.weight)  ,
                    ])
```